# Python I cant choose the elements by selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, bots, instagram

I am trying to get followers list on my instagram account.
I cant choose the elements via selenium because I run the program everytime and all tags changes.
I mean tags: XPATH, selectors,CLASS_NAME exc.
How can I fix that?

ITS MY CODE:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()                
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)    


service = Service("./chromedriver.exe")      

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,service=service) 
    
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/") 



user_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input')
pword = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[2]/div/label/input')

time.sleep(2)

user_name.send_keys("eren.i07")
pword.send_keys("07386658+ABC")


enter1= driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]')

enter1.click()

time.sleep(2)



profile = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#mount_0_0_L\/ > div > div > div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.x10cihs4 > div.x9f619.xvbhtw8.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1uhb9sk.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.x1q0g3np.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1qughib > div.x9f619.xjbqb8w.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.xdt5ytf.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1nhvcw1.x1dr59a3.xixxii4.x13vifvy.xeq5yr9.x1n327nk > div > div > div > div > div.x1iyjqo2.xh8yej3 > div:nth-child(8) > div > span > div > a > div')

time.sleep(3)



followers = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#mount_0_0_L\/ > div > div > div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.x10cihs4 > div.x9f619.xvbhtw8.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1uhb9sk.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.x1q0g3np.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1qughib > div.x1gryazu.xh8yej3.x10o80wk.x14k21rp.x17snn68.x6osk4m.x1porb0y > div:nth-child(2) > section > main > div > header > section > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a')
followers.click()

time.sleep(3)




response = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/eren.i07/followers/")
print(f"RESPONSE DEĞERİ= {response}")


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')



followers_count = soup.find("span",class_ = "html-span xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r xexx8yu x4uap5 x18d9i69 xkhd6sd x1hl2dhg x16tdsg8 x1vvkbs")


print(f"TAKİPCİ SAYISI:{followers_count}")


scroll = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"_aano")


scroll.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

ITS OUTPUT:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50495/devtools/browser/b03af9d2-df1d-4545-a5e5-d15d30a5dd73
[16928:1300:0213/212753.715:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(192)] [21:27:53.717] USB: usb_service_win.cc:105 SetupDiGetDeviceProperty({{A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0}, 6}) failed: Eleman bulunamad². (0x490)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\erenu\OneDrive\Masaüstü\PYTHON\2024---\fiverr\PROJECT2\main.py", line 82, in <module>
    profile = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#mount_0_0_L\/ > div > div > div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.x10cihs4 > div.x9f619.xvbhtw8.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1uhb9sk.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.x1q0g3np.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1qughib > div.x9f619.xjbqb8w.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.xdt5ytf.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1nhvcw1.x1dr59a3.xixxii4.x13vifvy.xeq5yr9.x1n327nk > div > div > div > div > div.x1iyjqo2.xh8yej3 > div:nth-child(8) > div > span > div > a > div')
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\erenu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 741, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\erenu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\erenu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#mount_0_0_L\/ > div > div > div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.x10cihs4 > div.x9f619.xvbhtw8.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1uhb9sk.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.x1q0g3np.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1qughib > div.x9f619.xjbqb8w.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.xdt5ytf.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1nhvcw1.x1dr59a3.xixxii4.x13vifvy.xeq5yr9.x1n327nk > div > div > div > div > div.x1iyjqo2.xh8yej3 > div:nth-child(8) > div > span > div > a > div"}
  (Session info: chrome=121.0.6167.161); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6CE074D02+56194]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CDFE04B2]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CDE876AA]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CDED16D0]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CDED17EC]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CDF14D77]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CDEF5EBF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CDF12786]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CDEF5C23]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CDEC4A45]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CDEC5AD4]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6CE3ED5BB+3695675]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6CE446197+4059159]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6CE43DF63+4025827]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6CE10F029+687785]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CDFEB508]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CDFE7564]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CDFE76E9]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6CDFD8094]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFD508A257D+29]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFD522EAA58+40]
```

I wrote the expectations and results on top..

Comment: Don't add spam in order to circumvent the rules of [SO]. It could easily get you banned.